# Puppeteer send POST and 302 redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to intercept a request, change the method to post and pass Data.

```
...
page.on('request', request => {
  payload = {...}
  var data = {'method': 'POST', 'postData': payload
  request.continue(data)
});

await page.goto(url_post_product)
```

The problem is the URL `url_post_product` doesn't return any body, the status_code is a 302 so I always have a TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded.

I think I need to know the location reponse and redirected it bur nothing happens when I try to incertecept the reponse.

```
page.on('response', response => {console.log(response.status())});
```

I know the request and posted data is well formed.

**EDIT**

[it's seems to a chromium bug:](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=937719)

[Puppeteer GitHub bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3973)